# How 3D figures are colored

Tags: 3d

I know how 3D points are projected. But how is a 3D cube colored. Does a 3d renderer convert a 3x3x3 cube to 54 points and project them with color???

Comment: You need to be more specific - what is 3x3x3 cube (a Rubik one?) and what do you mean by 'project them with color'? And most important - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: After research I can rephrase my question "How 3d objects are rasterized? sorry for misleading you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for **Painter's Algorithm** en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm.

**There are others**, but this one is **the simplest**.